# Quartz.net + Execute on Australian local time

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net, timezone-offset

I am new to Quartz.NET and I am having a hard time creating an event that will fire daily when its 11AM local time in Australia.

I know I have to use the ScheduleJob method but how do I go about adding the time for Australia? I am not very good with UTC/GMT. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Do you add triggers programmatically?

Comment: Yep! I added the trigger using the ScheduleJob method on the ISchedulerFactory instance

Comment: Could you post your code? I'm using Quartz.NET with Cron Triggers and it defaults to local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the `ToUniversalTime` method ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.100).aspx ) to convert local time to UTC. This isn't straightforward but stops you from fiddling with UTC yourself.